# Graphviz: vizualize data from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, graphviz

I have dataframe

```
ID  domain  search_term
111 vk.com  вконтакте
111 twitter.com фэйсбук
111 facebook.com    твиттер
222 avito.ru    купить машину
222 vk.com  вконтакте
333 twitter.com твиттер
333 apple.com   купить айфон
333 rbk.ru  новости
```

I need to print 3 graphics.
I use

```
domains = df['domain'].values.tolist()
search_terms = df['search_term'].values.tolist()
ids = df['ID'].values.tolist()
for i, (id, domain, search_term) in enumerate(zip(ids, domains, search_terms)):
    if ids[i] == ids[i - 1]:
        f = Digraph('finite_state_machine', filename='fsm.gv', encoding='utf-8')
        f.body.extend(['rankdir=LR', 'size="5,5"'])
        f.attr('node', shape='circle')
        f.edge(domains[i - 1], domains[i], label=search_terms[i])
    else:
        continue
f.view()
```

But it prints only graph to last to string and I get
[image: only one file with graph]
How can I get 3 graph?

Answer (score 0):

You create a new graph on each iteration. Take the creation out of the loop and just add the edges inside:

```
f = Digraph('finite_state_machine', filename='fsm.gv', encoding='utf-8')
f.body.extend(['rankdir=LR', 'size="5,5"'])
f.attr('node', shape='circle')
for i, (id, domain, search_term) in enumerate(zip(ids, domains, search_terms)):
    if ids[i] == ids[i - 1]:
        f.edge(domains[i - 1], domains[i], label=search_terms[i])
f.view()
```

If you want each iteration produce a new graph, use:

```
for i, (id, domain, search_term) in enumerate(zip(ids, domains, search_terms)):
    if ids[i] == ids[i - 1]:
        f = Digraph('finite_state_machine', filename='fsm.gv', encoding='utf-8')
        f.body.extend(['rankdir=LR', 'size="5,5"'])
        f.attr('node', shape='circle')
        f.edge(domains[i - 1], domains[i], label=search_terms[i])
        f.render(filename=str(id))
```

BTW, I removed the `else: continue` because it's redundant.

Comment: it return `RuntimeError: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tpdf', '-O', 'fsm.gv'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' path`

Comment: that seems unrelated problem. That's the only change you made?

Comment: I fix that problem. Can I save it to different files? (name of file is ID)

Comment: And why size of circles are differemt?

Comment: You want each iteration produce a different graph? So take the creation back inside the for loop and use `f.render(filename=id)` at the end of the loop (inside!)

Comment: when I add code to loop and write at the end `f.render(filename=id)` it return `TypeError: object of type 'long' has no len()`. I should add `f = Digraph('finite_state_machine', filename='fsm.gv', encoding='utf-8')
f.body.extend(['rankdir=LR', 'size="5,5"'])
f.attr('node', shape='circle')` to the loop after `if`?

Comment: It creates files, but in files not all path. there only 2 circle, but to `111` and `333` it should be three

Comment: I have no idea what are you trying to do. On each iteration you create only 1 edge. If you want more help please rephrase your question

Comment: I want to get result, that I can get with your first code. There are 3 edge. I want to save every edge to different file. Your code save it in different files. but first code return edges with 3, 2, 3 circles. But after saving to different file it return 1 edge in every file, but every edge contain only 2 circles